# How do I resolve error with insert() with Mongo BasicDBObject

Tags: mongodb

Hope this isn't too newBish of a question, but I created a collection of client users (as usersCollection), then I create a user like:

```
BasicDBObject user = new BasicDBObject("_id", username);
```

I append a couple more bits to it depending if I have them from the form that the user enters.

But then when I try to insert the user in the usersCollection...
usersCollection.insert(user);

My IDE complains that it cannot resolve method `insert(com.mongodb.BasicDBObject)`

I don't see the problem... I am using mongodb-driver 3.2.2... if that's even relevant.

Any clue what I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the piece of code where you instantiate the usersCollection collection?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `usersCollection` object class is `com.mongodb.DBCollection` . From the present information I can only deduce that it's of another type as it does not recognize the insert method.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps -  I didn't have that imported.  I did have  an import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject.

Comment: So it's actually a MongoCollection.  I declared private MongoCollection<Document> usersCollection; then in the DAO, DAO(final MongoDatabase blogDatabase) {
        usersCollection = blogDatabase.getCollection("users");
    }

Answer (score 0):

I changed directions... instead of using a DBObject I instantiated the collection as a document

```
MongoCollection<Document>
```

Next I created the user like:

```
Document user = new Document("_id", username);
```

(and appended some other bits after that)

Finally, to insert it, simply insertOne()

```
allUsers.insertOne(user);
```

Really not sure what I was doing wrong with DBObject but I do think I was making it more complicated than it needed to be. Thanks for the tips though, your questions helped push me to rethink why I was doing it that way to begin with.